Time served and logical propositions
You are at time served if you plead guilty [that is, you are releasable from prison without conditions at a prescribed date dictated by the prosecutor's discretion].
But you are not at time served if you do not plead guilty.
To be releasable, should you not plead guilty, you must meet criteria unrelated to the prosecutor's 'time served'.
Therefore, once the prosecutor states that you are at time served at X date, then whether you plead or not is irrelevant: you are releasable.
What are the logical elements here?

The first three paragraphs are premises.

[Parenthetical] to paragraph 1. A definition of to "be at time served": to be at time served means to be releasable without conditions.
Paragraph 1. A conditional stating: IF you plead guilty THEN you are at time served [i.e. releasable without conditions].
Paragraph 2. A conditional stating IF you do not plead guilty THEN you are not at time served [i.e. you are not releaseable without conditions].
Note, Paragraphs 1 and 2 can be combined into the bi-conditional: You are at time served [i.e. releaseable without conditions] IF AND ONLY IF you plead guilty.
Paragraph 3. A conditional stating IF you do not plead guilty AND you do not meet "criteria unrelated to the prosecutor's 'time served'" THEN you are not releaseable.

The fourth paragraph is a purported conclusion. I note though that it reasons from a premise about what the prosecutor states. None of the first three paragraphs provide any conclusions that can be drawn based on what the prosecutor states.
Together, these make up an argument. It is an invalid argument, given the disconnect between the premises and the conclusion.

+1 But I feel like you've just done somebody's homework...
